# Azure DevOps SpecFlow+ LivingDoc : Cannot edit feature files online

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, bdd, specflow

I cannot [edit SpecFlow feature files directly in the LivingDoc section of Azure DevOps](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow-livingdoc/en/latest/Viewing/Editing-Feature-Files.html).

What I dit :

- Installed the [Azure DevOps SpecFlow LivingDoc](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow-livingdoc/en/latest/Installation/Installation.html) extension
- Created an Azure DevOps reposity using Git
- Created a SpecFlow projet, containing the default `calculator.feature` file, without modifying it
- Created a YAML pipeline for building, testing and pushing to LivingDoc in Azure DevOps :

```
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:

- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '6.x'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: 'Poc.SpecFlowProject1/Poc.SpecFlowProject1.csproj'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: 'Poc.SpecFlowProject1/Poc.SpecFlowProject1.csproj'
  
- task: SpecFlowPlus@0
  inputs:
    generatorSource: 'FeatureFolder'
    projectFilePath: 'Poc.SpecFlowProject1'
    projectName: 'Test SpecFlow'
    testExecutionJson: 'Poc.SpecFlowProject1/**/TestExecution.json'
    projectLanguage: 'en'
    workItemPrefix: 'WI:'
    workItemUrlTemplate: 'https://dev.azure.com/my-org/my-project/_workitems/edit/{id}'
    bindingAssemblies: 'Poc.SpecFlowProject1/bin/**/Poc.SpecFlowProject1.dll'
    output: 'LivingDoc.html'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

The LivingDoc appears correctly in Azure DevOps, but the "Open in editor" button is missing:

[image]

[According to the doc](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow-livingdoc/en/latest/Viewing/Editing-Feature-Files.html) this button should be visible because I picked the "Feature Folder" option. [This documentation page](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow-livingdoc/en/latest/Generating/Configuring-the-Build-Step-in-DevOps.html) also states that I should see the button.

What else I tried :

- Creating a simple repository with single project
- Creating pipeline with Classic UI instead of YAML
- In pipeline, changing feature folder to "Poc.SpecFlowProject1/Features"
- Changing source option of the pipeline :

[image]
[image]

There is no log from the pipeline extension.

[Someone fixed it for him like that](https://support.specflow.org/hc/en-us/community/posts/360015896938/comments/7270920668445):

> The pipeline(yaml) was checking out the repository (and others) into a
> subdirectory of the build working directory. The paths for the doc
> task settings were prefixed with that subdirectory name. When we
> changed the pipeline to checkout the repo the normal way the button
> just came up.

Unfortunately I don't see anywhere where I can set that.

Any idea how to show this "Edit" button?